# Two finger scrolling with libinput not working, 18.04

Tags: xorg, touchpad, thinkpad, synaptics, libinput

As there are multiple threads to this topic, I hope someone can help me. From one day to another, my Touchpad stopped working properly, namely the two finger scrolling was deactivated for some reason.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 bionic on x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-58-generic kernel with a Thinkpad E480.

I am using libinput, which refuses to change the settings.

```
➤ xinput list              
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ ...
```

Scroll methods are listed as follows. For two-finger scrolling I want to set the value to 100.

```
libinput Scroll Methods Available (284):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (285):   0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (286):   0, 0, 1
```

No matter which scroll method I try to change (also as root), the result is the same:

```
➤ xinput set-prop 11 286 100
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  19
```

Further, the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-libinput.conf`, which I also copied to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf/` looks like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "ScrollMethod" "twofinger"
EndSection
```

Changing the number of priority did not help here as well.

Trying to change the driver to synaptics by reinstalling (or deinstalling) synaptics (libinput), as some suggested on similar threads, did not work.

The synclient seems to be not working, no matter which priority I give to any of the `.conf` files in  the `xorg.conf` directory

```
➤ synclient 
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

In the Xorg log I only find that my desired option cannot be loaded from the `.conf` file:

```
➤ grep -ie "touch" /var/log/Xorg.0.log 
[     6.212] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event4)
[     6.212] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[     6.212] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[     6.212] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[     6.212] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[     6.213] (II) event4  - PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[     6.213] (II) event4  - PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device is a pointer
[     6.213] (II) event4  - PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device removed
[     6.248] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[     6.248] (EE) libinput: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Failed to set scroll to twofinger
[     6.248] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[     6.248] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     6.248] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     6.248] (II) event4  - PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[     6.248] (II) event4  - PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device is a pointer
[     6.248] (EE) libinput: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Failed to set scroll to twofinger
[     6.248] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse0)
```

I am really desperate by now, since no solution working for others seems to help me.
Are there any suggestions? Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: You can usually enable 2-finger scrolling from the "keyboard and mouse" tab of Gnome Tweaks `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`. Can you check if it is enabled or disabled from there?

Comment: sorry, forgot to say, I am using xfce and not gnome, where the two-finger scrolling option does not show up. also in the gnome-tweaks the desired options is not available for me, so neither dis- or enabled.

Comment: From the author's self answer: *With the latest update the problem has been solved. It really appears like this was a bug and by no means an effect of false configuration.*

Answer (score 2):

> No matter which scroll method I try to change (also as root), the result is the same:
>
> ```
> ➤ xinput set-prop 11 286 100
> X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
>   Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
>   Serial number of failed request:  19
> ```

No need in root. You have a typo: `100` should be `1 0 0`, because it's three separate values *(I think they could've been better represented as "false" and "true" strings, but oh well)*.

Also, you're using a number in place of device and property. It might be okay for experiments, however if you want to add this command to autostart *(you probably do because `xinput` modifications are lost after XServer restarted)*, then you may find that these numbers may change from time to time, depending on curcumstances. Instead, use the actual string that identifies the device and the property.

The command you want is:

```bsh
xinput set-prop "PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "libinput Scroll Method Enabled" 1 0 0
```

> ```
> ➤ synclient
> Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
> ```

Oh, sorry, too many synaptics, it's confusing. Basically, the `synclient` was used to manage the deprecated synaptics driver, but you don't have it nor need it. It was obsoleted in preference of libinput. You may also want to read [this blog-post](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2016/12/xf86-input-synaptics-is-not-synaptics.html) from libinput maintainer.

---

Sorry, not gonna help with the xorg.conf file because IMO their syntax is a maze, and I'm not a person to advice on that. I'm personally just use `xinput` added to autostart. Hopefully someone will post an answer about xorg config.

Comment: thanks a lot! however, also with "1 0 0" instead of "100" i get ` X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) ... ` as answer

Comment: also the "twofinger' option is legit, i think, since it appears in the libinput manual:

Option "ScrollMethod" "string"
Enables  a  scroll  method. Permitted values are none, twofinger, edge, button.  Not all devices support all options, if an option is unsupported, the default scroll option for this device is used.

Comment: @enzo by any chance, could you be running Wayland? Offhand, if you're running pure Xorg *(no Wayland around)*, that looks like a bug.

Comment: @enzo a shot in the dark about the non-working twofinger option: I'm wondering if that documentation could be referring to libinput newer than the one you have *(Ubuntu typically has very old packages, latest libinput is 1.14.1, which is probably not what you're running)*.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest update the problem has been solved, it really appears like this was a bug and by no means an effect of false configuration. This would also explain why none of the supposed solutions helped in the end.

Thanks for reading.